# SQL querying from multiple tables and retrieving data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following tables which are represented in form of schema :

- Customer (cid: integer, cname: string, rating: integer, salary: real)
- Item (iid: integer, iname: string, type: string)
- Order (cid: integer, iid: integer, day:date, qty:real)

The problem is I don't know how can I search data from multiple tables and represent it in my software interface. Although I can represent it but I can't retrieve the data from the tables. So, here are the required data I needed to fetch.

I have to fetch:

1. Names of customers who’ve ordered item with id 100.
2. Names of Customers who’ve ordered a laptop (i.e., an item of type “laptop”).
3. Customers who’ve ordered a laptop and a desktop computer. The names of customers who’ve ordered all item.

Comment: using joins please see the link for samples [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php)

Comment: Looks like you are just dumping your homework on us.  @Andreas was kind enough to address it, but for future reference, I'd suggest that you read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  And before asking for a homework answer, show what you've tried yourself, then ask about the _specific_ problem you are having.  You learn nothing when someone just gives you an answer on a silver platter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions:

1. Names of customers who’ve ordered item with id 100.

   ***`select name from customer where cid in (select distinct(cid) from order where iid= 100) ;`***
2. Names of Customers who’ve ordered a laptop (i.e., an item of type “laptop”).

   ***`select name from customer where cid in (select distinct(cid) from order where iid=(select iid from item where type='laptop')) ;`***
3. Customers who’ve ordered a laptop and a desktop computer.
   The names of customers who’ve ordered all item

   ***`select name from customer where cid in (select distinct(cid) from order where iid in (select iid from item where type in ('laptop','desktop') )) ;`***

Comment: 1) `DISTINCT` is not a function, remove the `( )` parentheses. --- 2) `IN` clause implies `DISTINCT`, so remove the redundant `DISTINCT` keyword. --- 3) #2 **fails** if there is more than one `item` with `type = 'laptop'`. *(down-voted for this)* --- 4) #3 **fails** for invalid use of `IN` clause. Should be `type in ('laptop', 'desktop')`. *(down-voted for this)* --- 5) Query would return **incorrect result**, since it'll return customers who ordered a laptop *or* a desktop, but should only return customers who ordered *both*. *(down-voted for this)*

Comment: yeah you are right  #1  above queries are just samples accroding to postgresql and in postgres distinct is a function .   #2this is based on assumption that one item exits for type laptop , queries can change based on business logics #3 anyone can change the query accroding to their database and also accroding to business usecase , above queries just given an idea how one cana chiver these type of data and change accroding to chaning usecases , thanx for comment

Comment: I stand by what I said: `DISTINCT` is not a function, not even in PostgreSQL. Sure, PostgreSQL does have an *extension*, with an `ON ( ... )` sub-clause after the `DISTINCT` keyword, but the `ON` keyword means that the `( )` isn't function argument syntax. --- `select distinct(cid)` is actually `select distinct (cid)` and same as `select distinct cid`, except the column had been changed from a simple column name, to be an expression. The `( )` parentheses are allowed by the expression syntax, not the `DISTINCT` syntax.

Comment: I stand by what I said for #2: If I ordered 2 different laptops, i.e. not just a `qty = 2`, then inner select returns 2 `iid` values, and since SQL uses `iid=(...)`, not `iid in (...)`, the query will **fail** with "select returned more than one row".

Comment: I stand by my down-votes for #3, because an answer with flawed queries is not useful. You can't just give a bad answer and say "oh well, you'll need to fix the syntax errors and query logic yourself". That is certainly not useful. If you can't be bothered to show good valid examples, that might actually be something people can take and adjust for their data model, then don't bother answering. Yes, business use cases change, and examples must be adjusted accordingly, but at least show valid syntax and constructs.

Comment: Yer Andreas , you are correct , i will change my last query,  But i don't see any flaw in disctinct  as it does not have  syntax error  , weather () are allowed by disctinct or expression syntax  it is ruuning fine on my postgres instance  .  Thanx for correcting the last query which is logiicaly incorect and also syntaxt wise ,  Currently corrected it syntaxwise

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Names of customers who’ve ordered item with id 100.

We can do it by first running a query to find customer id's with an order that includes the given item id, then lookup the customers name. This is done with an `IN` clause.

```sql
SELECT c.cname
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE c.cid IN (
          SELECT o.cid
            FROM Order o
           WHERE o.iid = 100
       )
```

A customer will only be returned once, that is guaranteed by the Set semantics of the `IN` clause, but the same customer name might be returned multiple times, if the database allows multiple customers with the same name.

To only return the customer name once, even if there are multiple customers with the same name, we can use the `DISTINCT` clause. If we do that, we can change the query to use a normal `JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname
  FROM Order o
  JOIN Customer c ON c.cid = o.cid
 WHERE o.iid = 100
```

Which is better is a matter of taste, I believe they'll perform about the same. Personally, I prefer the first one.

---

> 2. Names of Customers who’ve ordered a laptop (i.e., an item of type “laptop”).

Same as before, but staring with a `WHERE` condition against the `Item` table.

```sql
SELECT c.cname
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE c.cid IN (
          SELECT o.cid
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
           WHERE i.type = 'laptop'
       )
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname
  FROM Item i
  JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
  JOIN Customer c ON c.cid = o.cid
 WHERE i.type = 'laptop'
```

---

> 3. Customers who’ve ordered a laptop and a desktop computer.
>    The names of customers who’ve ordered all item

When using `IN` clause, we just need to do it twice, to find customers that ordered both.

```sql
SELECT c.cname
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE c.cid IN (
          SELECT o.cid
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
           WHERE i.type = 'laptop'
       )
   AND c.cid IN (
          SELECT o.cid
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
           WHERE i.type = 'desktop'
       )
```

For the other way, we need to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` so we can check that customer ordered both.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname
  FROM Item i
  JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
  JOIN Customer c ON c.cid = o.cid
 WHERE i.type IN ('laptop', 'desktop')
 GROUP BY c.cid, c.cname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.type) = 2
```

Or we can mix the two styles.

```sql
SELECT c.cname
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE c.cid IN (
          SELECT o.cid
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Order o ON o.iid = i.iid
           WHERE i.type IN ('laptop', 'desktop')
           GROUP BY o.cid
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.type) = 2
       )
```

The third one is likely the best for performance.